# Is it possible to revert back to some commit without reset --hard?

Tags: git, version-control

I'm pretty new to git and came from mercurial. I did something wrong and pushed it, but some teammates could already pulled these wrong changes. So `reset --hard; push -f` is not an option. Is it possible to tell git that I want to commit changes so that it became is it was 2 commits ago? I mean something like this:

`master`:

```
commit 4 <<--- Remote/local master's head
   ^
   |
   |
commit 3
   ^
   |
   |
commit 2 <<-- I want git to craft changes so that commit 5 
   ^           is the same as commit 2
   |
   |
   |
commit 1
```

I want to git to produce changes so that `commit 5` changes files so that they become the same as they were at `commit 2`.

Is it possible to do?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can [revert](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-revert) the commit using git revert :

```
git revert commit3 commit4
```

This will create "reverse" commit, that will unmake the change you've make in the other commits.

The history will still be fast forward, on your way to push it without `-f`.

Comment: But is it possible to avoid specifying all the commits? I mean maybe there's a way to tell git that I want to revert all commits from `commit x` to `commit y`?

Comment: No, there is no way as far as I know. Using `commit3...commit4` is too dangerous, and git prevents it by default.

Comment: Got it. So, if we did something wrong we would have to revert commit by commit manually. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

There is no problem with forced push for your teammates, they just need to reset repository to last known good commit before pulling (`git reset --hard sha1-of-old-good-commit`) and then pulling changes again. Moreover, if you pushed to your "private" working branch, they shouldn't care about that branch at all, the problem only with `master` or another branch you merge all your work in.

So, to minimize problems with history rewriting (it is the nice feature of git, and it is good to use it and no need to deny that!) - always commit to private branch: you will be safe to rebase/squash/edit commits in that branch before merging with "master" branch.